# Creating an event via the Google Calendar API- authorization problem

Tags: python-3.x, authorization, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to work out how to create events on Google Calendar, using the API and Python. I got the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python) code to work, but I am having trouble with the [event creation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/create-events#python).

I have tried to add the event creation code at the end of the quickstart function, with only the mild change of moving the dates to be closer to today so I could more easily inspect the results, and the change to scope mentioned in the Create Event page. Here is my code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import datetime
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Google Calendar API.
    Prints the start and name of the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)

    # Call the Calendar API
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().isoformat() + 'Z' # 'Z' indicates UTC time
    print('Getting the upcoming 10 events')
    events_result = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', timeMin=now,
                                        maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
                                        orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = events_result.get('items', [])

    if not events:
        print('No upcoming events found.')
    for event in events:
        start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
        print(start, event['summary'])
    

    event = {
        'summary': 'Google I/O 2020',
        'location': '800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103',
        'description': 'A chance to hear more about Google\'s developer products.',
        'start': {
            'dateTime': '2020-12-05T09:00:00-07:00',
            'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
        },
        'end': {
            'dateTime': '2020-12-05T17:00:00-07:00',
            'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles',
        },
        'recurrence': [
            'RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2'
        ],
        'reminders': {
            'useDefault': False,
            'overrides': [
                {'method': 'email', 'minutes': 24 * 60},
                {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 10},
            ],
        },
    }

    event = service.events().insert(calendarId='primary', body=event).execute()
    print( 'Event created: %s' % (event.get('htmlLink')) )



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The error I get is:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?alt=json returned "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.". Details: "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">
```

Does anyone have any clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you delete the `token.pickle` file after modifying the scopes?

Comment: @ale13 I did not! That's what I was missing. When I looked around, I thought it would be some variable, but actually it was a file in the directory. It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `403 "Request had insufficient authentication scopes."` error message is self explanatory. However, since you are using the appropriate scopes for what you want to do, the issue is coming from the **token.pickle** file.

If you ran the *Quickstart* first and then modified your script directly without deleting the **token.pickle** file, then this error message is to be expected.

**How to solve this?** Simply delete the **token.pickle** file *whenever* you modify the scopes for your request.

#### Reference

- [Calendar API Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/python).